# Unity Build Size changes after the first build

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to build my unity android game but something strange happened. building for the first time after running unity gives me 110 MB in size and if I click the build button again without changing anything the second build size is 150 MB!!

how does this happen?

Here are both build reports:

First Build:

```
Build Report
Uncompressed usage by category (Percentages based on user generated assets only):
Textures               135.1 mb  87.0% 
Meshes                 0.0 kb    0.0% 
Animations             706.3 kb  0.4% 
Sounds                 11.8 mb   7.6% 
Shaders                486.9 kb  0.3% 
Other Assets           6.4 mb    4.1% 
Levels                 0.0 kb    0.0% 
Scripts                207.1 kb  0.1% 
Included DLLs          0.0 kb    0.0% 
File headers           734.6 kb  0.5% 
Total User Assets      155.4 mb  100.0% 
Complete build size    919.1 mb
```

Second Build:

```
Build Report
Uncompressed usage by category (Percentages based on user generated assets only):
Textures               135.1 mb  87.0% 
Meshes                 0.0 kb    0.0% 
Animations             706.3 kb  0.4% 
Sounds                 11.8 mb   7.6% 
Shaders                486.9 kb  0.3% 
Other Assets           6.4 mb    4.1% 
Levels                 0.0 kb    0.0% 
Scripts                207.1 kb  0.1% 
Included DLLs          0.0 kb    0.0% 
File headers           734.6 kb  0.5% 
Total User Assets      155.4 mb  100.0% 
Complete build size    957.1 mb
```

Notice the `Complete build size` in these two build reports.

Thanks

Comment: sounds like something if you can prove happens on a brand new project every time, to send as a bug report to unity

Comment: yup, it seems it's a unity bug.